# Tomato QoS: Why is some traffic unclassified when there are classifications for it?

Tags: router, tomato, qos

Ok, I am trying to tweak my router to give priority to some traffic.  My classifications seem to cover just about everything but I still see ~60 to ~80% of the traffic as unclassified:

```
TCP 192.168.1.100 64137 192.168.1.1 80 Unclassified
TCP 192.168.1.100 64175 192.168.1.1 80 Unclassified
TCP 192.168.1.100 64144 192.168.1.1 443 Unclassified
```

I assume that the 64### ports are just what my WAP uses to send packets inside my home network.  But my classifications seems to cover any traffic for destination ports 80 and 443: *(partial list)*

```
TCP      Dst Port: 80,443     High   WWW
TCP/UDP  Dst Port: 1024-65535 Lowest Bulk Traffic
```

Why do I have so much unclassified traffic if I have a classification that should cover it?

Answer (score 4):

As the [Tomato FAQ](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomatofaq#why%5Fare%5Fthere%5Funclassified%5Fcon) says, connections to/from your router are never classified.  This means that packets that are emitted by the router, or for the router, are not classified.  Other packets, that travel through the router but for which the router is not the sender or the destination, are classified.

Packets that are not classified thus include the three connections you mentioned in the question: they all are to 192.168.1.1, which I guess is your router.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer on the tomato FAQ, even though I don't really understand it:
http://www.polarcloud.com/tomatofaq#why_are_there_unclassified_con

Why does it say that "Connections that travel from the Internet to your computer or router" are unclassified.  What is the difference between that and normal inbound traffic that I *can* classify?

Comment: I think the difference is that "normal" inbound traffic is the inbound portion of an outgoing connection. So if you're PC starts a connection, it will be classified. If the connection is initiated from the outside to your PC, it will not be classified. I guess you have to distinguish between "incoming connections" and "inbound traffic". Every connection has inbound and outbound traffic, but not all connections are incoming.